# Is it possible to configure the version of snmp trap used by vCenter alarms?

Tags: vmware-vcenter, snmp

It's seems that vCenter alarms traps are sent in SNMPv1 only.  I would like to receive it as SNMPv2.  Is it possible to configure the version use by vCenter (I'm using version 5.0.0) ?  I can configure receiver but not the version.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I'm pretty sure v2c is the default, but technically it is pretty much identical (adds 64 bit counters) and configured at the same time/same place as v1.  So configuring SNMP (non v3) in vCenter should enable both v1 and v2c jointly.

The KB articles to configure SNMP are here: http://kb.vmware.com/selfservice/microsites/search.do?language=en_US&cmd=displayKC&externalId=1006438 for v1/v2c.

You can test with something like Paessler's SNMP test tool and choose v2c in the tool to verify connectivity: http://www.paessler.com/tools/snmptester

Comment: You are right about querying in v2.  But, my problem is the trap that is sent from vCenter (alarm trigger).  I'm trying to create a trap receiver in c# using SnmpSharpNet library.  The library tells me it's a v1 trap.  Receiving trap from Fortigate appliance tells me it's a v2. So I assume the library is ok.  Since you are saying they are pretty much the same, I'll check furthermore.

Comment: If this answers the question you posted, please accept it as the answer so the question doesn't go stale.  Thanks!